# Update Craft to a specific release from the CLI

Tags: manual-updates, cli

I know you can update to a specific release using the CLI, but I can not remember how to specify the version number in the update command!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this console command should do what you want:

`./craft update/update craft:3.7.2`

The docs for the update command are [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#update), if you want to pass in further options or update plugins at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, Martin!